# QGraphicsTextItem's position not updated?

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I'm using 
`QgisInterface->mapCanvas()->scene()->addItem(QGraphicsTextItem)`
to add a QGraphicsTextItem to the map canvas. The problem is that when I use the pan tool to move the display the added QGraphicsTextItem is not moving !
How can I make it update its position whenever the pan tool is used on the map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align the position of the item to the new canvas extent.  Either connect to the [QgsMapCanvas::extentsChanged()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a2a91ee382ce605e3382b74693f9c4d80) signal and update the `QGraphicsTextItem` from there.  Or derive a class from [QgsMapCanvasItem](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvasItem.html) and implement a `paint` method that takes the current map canvas extent into account (QgsMapCanvasItem has some methods in that direction).

[QgsTextAnnotationItem](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsTextAnnotationItem.html) might also fit your needs or at least be an example how to implement your class.